# Is $\mathbb{R}$ with the metric $d(x,y) = |\arctan(x) - \arctan(y)|$ totally bounded?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, real-numbers

I've come across a question which asks to prove or disprove whether $\mathbb{R}$ with the metric $$d(x,y) = |\arctan(x) - \arctan(y)|$$ is totally bounded. It includes a hint to use the theorem which states that a set $A$ is totally bounded if and only if every sequence in $A$ has a cauchy subsequence, but I have no clue how to apply this.

Comment: This space is just $(-\pi/2, \pi/2)$ with the usual metric in disguise. I think the definiton of total boundedness gives an easier proof of total boundedness  than messing about with sequences.

Comment: Can you think of any theorems about bounded sequences of real numbers which might apply?

Comment: @RobArthan So then it is definitely totally bounded right? But how does one go about using the definition to prove this? I've never done a proof using the definition.

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales I think it was something like: every bounded sequence has a cauchy subsequence. So because with this metric every sequence is bounded, every sequence has a cauchy subsequence $\Rightarrow$ it is totally bounded. Is this correct?

Comment: It's a bit long for a comment, so I've posted a more detailed hint as an answer. I hope that helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: this is equivalent to showing that the open interval $(-\pi/2, \pi/2)$ is totally bounded under the usual metric on $\Bbb{R}$. To prove the latter claim, you can just work from the definition: a metric space $X$ is totally bounded if, for any $\varepsilon > 0$, there is a finite collection of balls of radius $\varepsilon$ whose union contains $X$. So take $X = (-\pi/2, \pi/2)$ and let $\varepsilon > 0$ be given. Choose $n \in \Bbb{N}_{>0}$ such that $\frac{1}{n} < \varepsilon$ and for each $i \in \Bbb{Z}$ such that $\frac{i}{n} \in (-\pi/2, \pi/2)$, let $B_i = B(\frac{i}{n}, \varepsilon)$ (the ball centred on $\frac{i}{n}$ of radius $\varepsilon$. Then the $B_i$ comprise a finite set of balls of radius $\varepsilon$ whose union contains $(-\pi/2, \pi/2)$. So $(-\pi/2, \pi/2)$ is totally bounded.

To transfer this to $\Bbb{R}$ under the given metric, just take the $B_i$ as above and apply $\tan$.